# LeetCode: FloodFill C#

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, depth-first-search

https://leetcode.com/problems/flood-fill/

> An image is represented by a 2-D array of integers, each integer
>   representing the pixel value of the image (from 0 to 65535).
>
> Given a coordinate (sr, sc) representing the starting pixel (row and
>   column) of the flood fill, and a pixel value newColor, "flood fill"
>   the image.
>
> To perform a "flood fill", consider the starting pixel, plus any
>   pixels connected 4-directionally to the starting pixel of the same
>   color as the starting pixel, plus any pixels connected 4-directionally
>   to those pixels (also with the same color as the starting pixel), and
>   so on. Replace the color of all of the aforementioned pixels with the
>   newColor.
>
> At the end, return the modified image.

```
Example 1:
Input: 
image = [[1,1,1],[1,1,0],[1,0,1]]
sr = 1, sc = 1, newColor = 2
Output: [[2,2,2],[2,2,0],[2,0,1]]
Explanation: 
From the center of the image (with position (sr, sc) = (1, 1)), all pixels connected 
by a path of the same color as the starting pixel are colored with the new color.
Note the bottom corner is not colored 2, because it is not 4-directionally connected
to the starting pixel.
Note:

The length of image and image[0] will be in the range [1, 50].
The given starting pixel will satisfy 0 <= sr < image.length and 0 <= sc < image[0].length.
The value of each color in image[i][j] and newColor will be an integer in [0, 65535].
```

Please review for performance and coding style.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace ArrayQuestions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// https://leetcode.com/problems/flood-fill/
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class FloodFillTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void ExampleTest()
        {
            int[][] image = { new[] { 1, 1, 1 }, new[] { 1, 1, 0 }, new[] { 1, 0, 1 } };
            int sr = 1;
            int sc = 1;
            int newColor = 2;
            int[][] expected = { new[] { 2, 2, 2 }, new[] { 2, 2, 0 }, new[] { 2, 0, 1 } };
            FloodFillDFS dfs = new FloodFillDFS();
            dfs.FloodFill(image, sr, sc, newColor);
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected[i],image[i] );
            }

        }
    }

    public class FloodFillDFS
    {
        public int[][] FloodFill(int[][] image, int sr, int sc, int newColor)
        {
            int oldColor = image[sr][sc];
            DFS(image, sr, sc, newColor, oldColor);
            return image;
        }

        //make sure to check first the corner cases
        private void DFS(int[][] image, int sr, int sc, int newColor, int oldColor)
        {
            if (sr < 0 || sc < 0 || sr >= image.Length || sc >= image[0].Length || image[sr][sc] == newColor || image[sr][sc] != oldColor)
            {
                return;
            }

            image[sr][sc] = newColor;
            DFS(image, sr - 1, sc, newColor, oldColor);
            DFS(image, sr + 1, sc, newColor, oldColor);
            DFS(image, sr, sc - 1, newColor, oldColor);
            DFS(image, sr, sc + 1, newColor, oldColor);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you give -1 please explain why, I would like to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would split the if to 3 variables and give each a name : out of image,  isVisited and isOriginalColor or something similar.

I don't know what sr means, I would use row and col.

FloodFill return image  but dfs change the original image, It can confuse the user of the class.

Comment: thanks for the review, FloodFill suppose to change the original image. like when you paint a shape in Paint.