# LeetCode: FloodFill Rust

Tags: rust

Hi I'm implementing a few leetcode examples in Rust. https://leetcode.com/problems/flood-fill/

(looks to be same question as [LeetCode: FloodFill C#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/240274/leetcode-floodfill-c))

The input is one matrix, a position and its new colour. The output is the modified matrix

```
// Input: 
// image = [[1,1,1],[1,1,0],[1,0,1]]
// sr = 1, sc = 1, newColor = 2
// Output: [[2,2,2],[2,2,0],[2,0,1]]
// Explanation: 
// From the center of the image (with position (sr, sc) = (1, 1)), all pixels connected 
// by a path of the same color as the starting pixel are colored with the new color.
// Note the bottom corner is not colored 2, because it is not 4-directionally connected
// to the starting pixel.
```

I use `q.pop_front()` to fill the neighbouring cells first. Is `VecDeque` the best data structure for this que?

I do a lot of casting from between `i32` and `usize` as I want to be able to check if index is out of bounds by subtracting 1. Is there a better way?

Is `if (0..image.len()).contains(x1)` better than `if x1>=0 && x1<image.len()` for the range check?

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

  fn flood_fill(mut image: Vec<Vec<i32>>, sr: i32, sc: i32, new_color: i32) -> Vec<Vec<i32>> {

      let mut q:VecDeque<(i32,i32)> = VecDeque::new();
      q.push_back((sr,sc));

      let c0 = image[sr as usize][sc as usize];
      if c0 != new_color {
          while ! q.is_empty() {
              if let Some((sr,sc))=q.pop_front() {  
                  if image[sr as usize][sc as usize] == c0 {
                      image[sr as usize][sc as usize] = new_color;
                      for delta in vec![(-1,0),(1,0),(0,-1),(0,1)] {
                          let new_r:i32 = sr+delta.0;
                          let new_c:i32 = sc+delta.1;
                          if (0..image.len() as i32).contains( &new_r ) && (0..image[0].len() as i32).contains( &new_c){
                              q.push_back((new_r,new_c));
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      image
  }

#[cfg(test)]
mod test{
#[test]
    fn test_lc_default(){
        assert_eq!(super::flood_fill(vec![vec![1 as i32 ,1,1],vec![1,1 as i32,0],vec![1,0,1]],1, 1, 2),vec![vec![2,2,2],vec![2,2,0],vec![2,0,1]]) ;
    }
}
```

[image: Still need some work on memory]
It looks like I could use some memory optimization too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Formatting

I assume the indentation to be a copy-paste error when removing the
boilerplate `struct Solution` mandated by LeetCode.

Run `cargo fmt` on your code to conform to the standard Rust
formatting guidelines.

## Interface

LeetCode made a poor choice by using `Vec<Vec<i32>>` to represent a
two-dimensional array, which is generally inefficient as it stores
elements in multiple segmented allocations, incur double indirection
costs, and fail to maintain proper structure (against jagged arrays).
We can't do anything against this, though, so I'll ignore it for the
rest of the post.

Similarly, `i32` is not ideal for color representation — a
dedicated type (e.g., `struct Color(i32);`) is clearly superior.  At
the very least, we can somehow improve readability by using a type
alias and use it consistently for colors in the code:

```rust
type Color = i32;
```

## `i32` vs. `usize`

Generally, it is preferred to store and compute indexes in `usize`,
which is the natural type for this purpose.  One way you can avoid
subtracting `1` is by using `usize::MAX` and `wrapping_add`.

To convert from the `i32` values that the function receives,
[`try_from`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html#method.try_from) is preferred over `as`, since the latter silently
truncates invalid values.  `unwrap` can be used here since it's for
LeetCode; in real-world code, the error should be handled accordingly.

> Is `if (0..image.len()).contains(x1)` better than `if x1>=0 && x1<image.len()` for the range check?

I'd say yes.  It indicates the intent more clearly.

## Simplifying control flow

Instead of wrapping everything in an `if` expression, check for
`image[sr][sc] == new_color` and return early.

## `while let`

This:

```rust
while !cells.is_empty() {
    if let Some((sr, sc)) = cells.pop_front() {
```

is just a convoluted way of saying

```rust
while let Some((sr, sc)) = cells.pop_front() {
```

---

Here's how I modified your implementation:

```rust
type Color = i32;

pub fn flood_fill(
    mut image: Vec<Vec<Color>>,
    sr: i32,
    sc: i32,
    new_color: Color,
) -> Vec<Vec<Color>> {
    use std::collections::VecDeque;
    use std::convert::TryFrom;

    let sr = usize::try_from(sr).unwrap();
    let sc = usize::try_from(sc).unwrap();

    let initial_color = image[sr][sc];

    if initial_color == new_color {
        return image;
    }

    let height = image.len();
    let width = image[0].len();

    let mut cells: VecDeque<(usize, usize)> = VecDeque::new();
    cells.push_back((sr, sc));

    while let Some((sr, sc)) = cells.pop_front() {
        let cell = &mut image[sr][sc];

        if *cell != initial_color {
            continue;
        }

        *cell = new_color;

        const OFFSETS: &[(usize, usize)] = &[(0, usize::MAX), (usize::MAX, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0)];

        for (delta_r, delta_c) in OFFSETS.iter().copied() {
            let new_r = sr.wrapping_add(delta_r);
            let new_c = sc.wrapping_add(delta_c);

            if new_r < height && new_c < width {
                cells.push_back((new_r, new_c));
            }
        }
    }

    image
}
```

Comment: wrapping add not really the thing he wanted to do i think. it wraps size of integer (255+1 => 0 for u8 , for example) , but he adds point offsets, and it will not work, coz he checks image bounds, not an integer bounds.

Comment: also bfs and dfs not really different in this case, because he need to fill color field, not find path in it.

Comment: dfs bfs is only if poping from the front or the back of the queue

Comment: Thanks for feedback, auto format and `while let Some(x) = cells.pop_front()` are habits I will do more of. I `try_from()` instead of `as i32` is also good however I think it is clearer to use a signed type for subtraction than using the wraparound trick - it is too similar to the abnormality we use in C all the time `unsigned int = -1`

Comment: @Sugar `.wrapping_add(usize::MAX)` to a `usize` value is equivalent to `.wrapping_sub(1)`, because \$\mathbb{Z} / 2^{n}\mathbb{Z}\$ forms a ring under the wrapping operations.  The image bounds, of course, has to be checked separately.  I was also relying on valid indexes being strictly less than `usize::MAX`; that is, `usize::MAX` itself is always treated as an out-of-range value.

Comment: @Simson You're welcome.  The wraparound hack is indeed sub-optimal, so I tried to present it as an option only (as opposed to a recommendation).  I don't like signedness conversion either, so I took this approach instead, but that's purely subjective.

Comment: @L.F. but he don't need any wrapping operations. Clamping, yes, not wrapping

Comment: @Sugar The wrapping was to work around `usize` not supporting `+ (-1)`, not to clamp the index to the range.  We can of course use an array of closures or something along those lines, but I didn't think that would be clearer than `.wrapping_add(usize::MAX)`.